# What's the tallest Large Underworld possible?

Tags: terraria

What's the tallest Large Underworld possible? I've had my Expert one that starts at 3000' below and is ~300 feet tall, and one of my Master ones appears to be ~500 feet tall, starting at ~3264, and I think I got shafted by my Expert World, making my Wall Of Flesh kill a lot harder due to less freedom...

So, now I'm wondering, if my first Wall kill was in one of the hardest a.k.a shortest Underworlds, what's the easiest, a.k.a tallest?

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki page on [The Underworld](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/The_Underworld)

> The Underworld starts at about 3000 feet (1500 tiles) underground in a large world, at about 2000 feet (1000 tiles) underground in a medium world, and at about 1300 feet (650 tiles) underground in a small world.

With undergroud being defined here as being below the surface level according to the [Depth Meter](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Depth_Meter)

According to Underworld section on the [Layers](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Layers#Underworld) page:

> This layer consists of the bottom 400 feet of the map, below the Cavern layer.

With 400 feet being equivalent to 200 tiles.

Comment: I'll have to personally confirm that at some point. Thanks for finding that!

Comment: I assume that Seed doesn't matter, or does "Don't dig up" make the Underworld deeper? I might've used that for the world that was deeper than usual.

Answer (score -1):

No fixed height. The underworld can be anywhere between what you said, or bigger, no one knows currently.

Comment: Do you know the specific numbers for heights taller than 500 at least?